# Extracting data from two tables

Tags: join, outer-join

I have two tables "CAR" -it's fields are- (car_id,name), the second table "CARSFORSALE" contains cars for sale (id,car_id,....)
How i can get 10 rows from "CARSFORSALE" table for each car_id in one query

that mean if i have 7 car_id my result will be <=70

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1,car_id
union all
select 2,car_id
union all
select 3,car_id
union all
select 4,car_id
union all
select 5,car_id
union all
select 6,car_id
union all
select 7,car_id
union all
select 8,car_id
union all
select 9,car_id
union all
select 10,car_id
```